# Does the essential supremum $esssup(f_{\omega})_{\omega \in \Omega}$ of a collection of measureable functions exist?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, almost-everywhere, measurable-functions

In Measure and Integration Theory class we saw the following definition of an essential supremum of a collection of functions:

> Definition: Let $(f_{\omega})_{\omega \in \Omega}$ be a collection of measurable functions mapping from $X$ to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. Then a measurable map $h$ is called the essential supremum of $(f_{\omega})_{\omega \in \Omega}$, $$h=esssup_{\omega \in \Omega}f_{\omega}$$, if it satisfies $f_{\omega} \leq h$ $\mu$-a.e. for all $\omega \in \Omega$ and if $h \leq h'$ $\mu$-a.e. for every measurable $h'$ from $X$ to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ which satisfies $f_{\omega} \leq h'$ $\mu$-a.e. for all $\omega \in \Omega$. Where $\Omega$ is an arbitrary Index set.

Then we were given the following theorem:

> Theorem: Suppose that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. For every family $(f_{\omega})_{\omega \in \Omega}$ the essential supremum $esssup(f_{\omega})_{\omega \in \Omega}$ exists and is $\mu$-a.e. unique. Moreover, there exists a countable set $J \subseteq \Omega$ with $esssup(f_{\omega})_{\omega \in \Omega}=\sup_{j \in J}f_{i}$ pointwise.

My confusion was with the following part of the proof. We defined $\mathcal{A}:=\{ A \subseteq \Omega : A$ Is countable $\}$. Then for each $A \in \mathcal{A}$, set $g_{A} := \sup_{j \in A} f_{j}$, $c_{A} := \int g_{A} d \mu$ and $c:=\sup_{A \in \mathcal{A}} c_{A}$. Let $(A_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{A}$ with $c_{A_{n}} \nearrow c$.......

1) How does such a sequence of sets $(A_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ even exist if the set $\mathcal{A}$ does not have to be countable nor ordered?

2) Or is there maybe another source on how to prove this? I searched through books in our Library at uni but could not find even the definition in the Measure and Integration books.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: axiom of choice?

Comment: To my understanding, the existence of a Choice Function on the set $\mathcal{A}$ (hence using the axiom of choice) does not imply that one chooses the sequence to be strictly increasing nor converging to to $c$. But hey I could be wrong I'm just in my second year of studying mathematics.

Comment: Every bounded sequence of numbers contains a convergent subsequence to the supremum (you can just use the definition to prove this).  Now just take the corresponding sets from $\mathcal{A}$

Comment: Hmm... I still don't see how I could construct such a sequence of the sets. Could you maybe explain a little further? What bounded sequence of numbers are you referring to?

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE oooooh I see it now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was pointet out by @Euler....IS_ALIVE, in the comments to my question, one needs to use the Axiom of choice or the weaker form of it, the [Axiom of countable choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice). Let me explain, because one can use the following Theorem:

One can construct a set $\{c_{A}:A \in \mathcal{A}\}$ set of $c_{J}$'s. In the proof $c_{A} := \int g_{A} d \mu$ is bounded by $\mu(X)< \infty$ from above for all $A \in \mathcal{A}$, hence for every countable subset of the index set $\Omega$.

Now one can apply the following Theorem

> Theorem: Every subset $M \subset \mathbb{R}$ which is bounded from above by a real number $a \in \mathbb{R}$ has a convergent subsequence to $\sup{M}$, where $\sup$ denotes the supremum.

The proof idea goes as follows:

If $\sup{M} \in M$ then just set $x_{n}=\sup{M}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

If $\sup{M}$ is not in $M$ then fix an Element $x_{0}$ in $M$ assuming that $M$ is not empty. Then by Definition of the supremum there exists an Element in $\Lambda_{1} = \{ x \in M : x> \sup{M} - x_{0} \}$. Using the axiom of choice (or the weaker version "Axiom of countable choice") one can choose an Element $x_{1} \in \Lambda_{1}$. Since by Definition of the supremum such an Element must exists. Now one can continue this and for a general $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists an $x_{n} \in \Lambda_{n}=\{x \in M: x> \sup{M} - x_{n-1}\}$. Therefore one has constructed an increasing sequence $x_{n} \leq x_{n+1}$ that converges to $\sup{M}$.

This theorem can now be used to assert existence of such a countable sequence $c_{A_{n}}$ in $\{c_{A}:A \in \mathcal{A}\}$ which converges to $c$. Then the set of index sets $(A_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ also exists and every $A_{n}$ is countable.